# Calling a method error

Tags: c#, class, math, methods

I'm stuck with my code, I feel like I'm really overlooking something, but I'll ask anyway, because everything is learning! I'm trying to call this method, but I'm not really sure how to do it, I've a segment of my code that I'm working with.

```
public double Math2(double num1)
{
    return num1 * 1.5;            
}

public double Math3(double num2, double num1)
{
    return num2 * num1;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return //num3 + " " +
```

I tried calling Math2 like

```
return num3 + " " + Math2;
```

but it gave me an error. What exactly am I doing wrong? Thanks for helping a noob out!

Comment: `Math2` is a method that takes a double, so you need to call it. and convert the result to a string E.g. `Math2(42).ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        doube num3=34; 
        return num3.ToString() + " " + Math2(44).ToString();
    }
```

You need to pass data to argument of your method Math2().

Hope Helps.

Comment: FYI the `.ToString()` is unnecessary in this case

Comment: @MagikM18 I edited my answer. I think we need .ToString(), because we need to return string and the method and the num3 field type is decimal

Comment: I believe that `operator+` automatically calls `.ToString()` on the object that is being concatenated to a string.